# POST submitted form displays values in URL. Shouldn't it hide them?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, http-post

When I use HttpPost shouldn't the form values be hidden in my URL?

Here's the Razor code I'm using to generate a confirm page for payment:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Checkout", new { amount = Model.PackageCost, currency = "$", itemDescription = Model.PackageDescriptor, type = "digital" }, FormMethod.Post))
{    
    <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" class="btn primary frmsubmit" />
}
```

In my HTML, this is generated:

```
<form action="/Checkout?amount=50&amp;currency=%24&amp;itemDescription=Paquete%20Gold50%20%7C%2050%24%20(59%20lances)&amp;type=digital" method="post">    
    <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" class="btn primary frmsubmit" />
</form>
```

And when I click the Confirm button to submit the form, this is the URL I'm lead to:

```
http://localhost:5868/Checkout?amount=50&currency=%24&itemDescription=Paquete%20Gold50%20%7C%2050%24%20%2859%20lances%29&type=digital
```

So what gives? Why aren't the values being hidden if it's a POST form?

Comment: Yes, except those are not form values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because those are not the form values, but the route values. The form values are the values of the `<input >` tags.

I assume you don't want any route values(leave out the third parameter) and instead create `<input ...>` tags with an appropriate default value. If the normal user should not see them use `<input type="hidden">` (This is obviously not a security feature).

You should also use anti request forgery tokens.

Comment: Possible solutions? Creating a form with the value, and hide them using CSS?

Comment: `<input type="hidden">` can be used to add additional, non visible fields to a post-form. But obviously they still can be read and manipulated by a malicious user.